# How to instrument angular 6 project for code coverage using istanbul

Tags: angular, typescript, code-coverage, istanbul

I want to only instrument my angular 6 project source code (ts files).
As I don't have any unit test cases, so I'm not able to use the angular cli inbuilt code coverage features.

The instrumented code will be running against selenium based automation test scripts.
Note: I'm able to instrument the (.js) files uisng istanbul but not the (.ts) file for code coverage.